# Filtering a SELECT group using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to filter the options of a large select group based on text input in a textbox. I am currently using this code to filter from a `SELECT` group based on the text of a input box.

Can you please tell me whether there is a more efficient way of doing this? My `SELECT` group is very large with around 7000 entries, which is why I am looking for the most optimized way.

```
<script>
var fullcelllist = $();
var lastVal ="";

$(window).load(function(){
    $("#celllist option").each(function(){
        fullcelllist.push($(this).val());
    });
});

$("#filtercell").keyup(function() {
    if(lastVal.length < $(this).val().length){
        $("#celllist option:not([value*='"+$(this).val().toUpperCase()+"'])").each(function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }else{
        stregexp = new RegExp($(this).val(),"i");
        temparr = $.grep(fullcelllist, function (value) {
        if(value.match(stregexp)) return value;
            return null;
        });
        newopt = "";
        temparr.sort();
        $.each(temparr,function(i){
            newopt += "<option value='"+temparr[i]+"'>"+temparr[i]+"</option>"; 
        });
        $("#celllist").html("");
        $("#celllist").append(newopt);
    }
    lastVal = $(this).val();
});
</script>

<input type="text" id="filtercell">
<select id ="celllist" multiple="multiple">
// HERE all OPTIONS using PHP
<select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your jQuery could be somewhat more efficient if you minimize `$(...)` element look-ups by storing them as variables or chaining them.

Also, I think you will see some benefit to replacing some jQuery constructs with their pure JS alternatives (`$.each` -> `for`, etc..)

Check out [this set of jsPerf tests](http://jsperf.com/caching-jquery-selectors) from [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10055208/363701).

```
<script>
var fullcelllist = $(),
    lastVal ="",
    $celllistOption = $("#celllist option");

// ...

$("#filtercell").keyup(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        $thisVal = $this.val();

// ...
```

Comment: thanks .. i didn't know that reusing $(...) would hamper my performance! Good to know, I'll change accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
var options = $("#celllist option"); // cache all your options right away

$("#filtercell").keyup(function () {
  var stregexp = new RegExp($(this).val(), "i"); // your regex
  $("#celllist").append(options); // append will add all missing options
  var x = $.grep(options, function (value) { // get all the options where value doesn't match
    return !value.value.match(stregexp)
  });
  $(x).detach(); // detach them from dom
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/WzwEq/)